# Will an asynchronus-Ajax request be completed if I instantly reload or close my page after it's being sent to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

For example if I do this request with jQuery's Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/some/request',
            type: 'POST',
            data: [{my: 'dummy', data: 'lata'}],
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
        });

        window.location.href = '/my/parent/location';
    });
});
```

So I'm interested:

> **Will my action be completed on the server nevermind if I'm refreshing the page just right after the initial request is sent?**

Comment: If the server received the ajax call, yes it will! Since you're redirecting right away, it probably won't have time to send it, so no it won't.

Comment: is there an event/property or something in jQuery which with I can check this?

Comment: There sure is, it's called the success callback of the ajax function?

Comment: yes, I knew about it already :) also there's a "complete" event which is executed after success or error handlers ... but this will work just fine :) I'll update my labels, tables, elements just when the user clicks the element, and I'll leave ajax to complete itself :)

Comment: Ive done this a few times, firing off an ajax call onbeforeunload etc. to send something to the server just as the page redirects without waiting for a response in the ajax function, and if I remember correctly Chrome and Firefox sent the call, and everything worked fine, while Opera and IE redirected before the ajax call had time to be sent to the server for some reason. This is some time ago, and I remember having to rewrite it because of issues, so just waiting for the success handler is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is synchronous.. So it will be immediately redirected irrespective of the Request..

You can call that in the **success callback** of your `Ajax Request` instead..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/some/request',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {my: 'dummy', data: 'lata'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function() {
                window.location.href = '/my/parent/location';
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: I know the basics of jQuery and it's ajax component. read my last comment on the question :) thank you for your answer anyways :)